# How can I get the value of a group and define it in one line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I define a regex group in JavaScript and access it all in one line?

I have tried to use eval to get the value of the defined regex group:

```
let str = `
global stuff = 1;
global h = 0;
function inc(arg) {
    inc = inc + 1;
};
main {
    repeat(inc, 10);
}
`;
str = str.replace(/repeat\((.*?|$1), (.*?|$2)\)/gm, "$1".repeat(eval("$2")));
console.log(str);
```

I expected the output to be

```
`global h = 0;
function inc(arg) {
    h = h + 1;
};
main {
    inc;
    inc;
    inc;
    inc;
    inc;
    inc;
    inc;
    inc;
    inc;
    inc;
}`
```

, because I want to convert `repeat(inc, 10);` to

```
inc;
inc;
inc;
...
```

, but it gives me this error: `ReferenceError: $2 is not defined`. I know what I'm doing here may look very obscure, but it's part of the code for a compiler I'm making for a programming language I'm making.

Comment: Why all in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replace method can take a function. This code does what you asked for, all in one line.

```js
let str = `
global stuff = 1;
global h = 0;
function inc(arg) {
    inc = inc + 1;
};
main {
    repeat(inc, 10);
}
`;
str = str.replace(/(\s+)repeat\((.*?|$1), (.*?|$2)\);/gm, (match, p0, p1, p2) => (p0 + p1 + ";").repeat(p2));

console.log(str);
```